# How to use only the form elements from jQuery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I don't need the most parts of jQuery-mobile, but the form elements are awesome, so I want to use them. But jQuery-mobile adds a lot of classes and div to the page on startup. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you will not be able to use just a part of the jquery mobile framework.But with the release of jQuery Mobile version 1.0 you should be able to do so.

From the jQuery mobile website

> Download builder: In the works
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

[Reference link](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/)

Answer (score 0):

check the following link. It just look alike jQueryMobile's idea [jQuery Form Transform](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements)